# Is it possible to create a volume scatter Cycles material with "real" scattering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I might not understand the Volume Scatter material properly...

A real "milky" glass (like diffuse volumetric plexiglas) would scatter light in any direction. If you put a printed paper with text behind it, you could read the text when it is closer to the object. If you move the text further away it gets more and more blurry until it becomes unreadable.

I try to do the same with Cycles:
[image]
The first sphere has 0 scatter density, the second has 0.1.
The second gets darker as the light "scatters" inside but the text remains as sharp as with the first sphere.
In reality, the light from the texture would be also scattered and therefore the text would be distorted.

Is there a way to achieve this effect with cycles?

UPDATE:
I increased the amount of Volume samples (thanks for the suggestion) but it doesn't change the result. The plate on the right should show a  more distorted texture because it is further away:

[image]

In reality there is a major difference between a sheet of transparent plastic which has a rough surface texture and one which is glossy on the outside but has a scattering inner volume.
This is what I would like to achieve:

[image]

These are volumetric plastic materials whit different amount of scattering per millimeter. They have a very different appearance then surface treated materials.

Comment: First, try to turn up the number of volume bounces in Light Paths

Comment: But I think Roughness will approximate this with better performance, the difference is that scattering will only occur at the surface interface, and not at steps inside the sphere

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion with the bounces! Unfortunately the effect remains the same. I updated the original post with a sample image. I'm afraid that cycles will not be able to reproduce this exact behavior. Surface based roughness creates a very different effect, therefore I can't go that road. (I already have such materials and I have to show them side by side, like their real counterparts.)